# How to keep the state of a checkbox component in dynamic list with Angular?

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot, rest, checkbox

I have a problem with my “Affect Subject Page”, I would save the state from the checkbox after reloading or refreshing page.
I am using dynamic data retrieve from a MySQL database using the Restful ws to communicate with a back project developed with Spring boot.

Below is the scenario for assigning the subject to a learner:

1. The trainer chooses the subject to assign:

- page "Les sujets"
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCUKM.png)
- sujet.component.ts :
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNcYj.png)
- sujet.component.html :
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzUi4.png)

2. It can assign the subject to one or more learners, by clicking on the checkbox button:

- page "Affecter Sujet"
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dNXM.png)
- affectsujet.component.ts :
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2DRY.png)
- affectsujet.component.html :
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUgzo.png)

Comment: You can store enrollment state in a DB table using a spring ws.
Use another ws to get the enrollment state of a subject and show in UI.